# How would user work with GIT from browser

Tags: .net, git, storage

How would you provide a user with ability to change code in browser without downloading anything on local machine, and commit that code to GIT?

Clarification: original question contained additional points, now moved to [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672909/can-some-cloud-file-storage-connect-to-git).

Comment: Too many question in a single post. I suggest to split it.

Comment: The answer to your first question is "simple": You have to automate git. Basically, you have to store the file into a repository, commit it, then push/pull. This will be more complicated if others are allowed to commit and push to the same central repository though, as you might then have to handle merge conflicts.

Comment: Agreed, I am splitting this question

Comment: Git itself doesn't have one. Whether you can even build one (that doesn't actually just *run* Git anyway), depends on the services offered by the hosting provider. So the answer for Git is just "you don't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to the first question only.

> How would you provide a user with ability to change code in browser without downloading anything on local machine, and commit that code to GIT?

Gitab offers a full featured Web IDE like in the following snapshot:

[image: Gitlab Web IDE]

**Edit**

Here is the screenshot about the console activation button.

[image: Console activation button]

Comment: I wasn't being specific of GitLab, however I did found this as well: https://github.com/zvizvi/GitHub-Web-IDE 
I any case, interesting idea to consider. Love your logo btw :)

Answer (score 3):

If you to write your own code that will handle git in the browser you can use [the isomorphic-git library](https://isomorphic-git.org/). To see it in action you can check my [Git Web Terminal](https://git-terminal.js.org/) (it uses an older version of the library, and not everything is implemented).